# How to align wrapped lines within a list item?

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="key">Foo:</span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="key">Bar:</span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="key">FooBar:</span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="key">Foo:</span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
    </li>    
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

li .key {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Run this code at http://jsfiddle.net/Bjpzm/

I am not satisfied with the output. I want the "Lorem Ipsum" text to be neatly separated from the bold text inside the `.key` class. So I would want that when the long "Lorem Ipsum" text wraps, the wrapped lines don't begin from the very left edge of each blue box. Instead, the wrapped lines should begin right under the first word of each text.

Let me demonstrate what the current output looks like and what I want instead in ASCII form.

The current output looks like:

```
Foo:     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Bar:     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
volutpat.

FooBar:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Foo:     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse
molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero
eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum
zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
```

But I want this:

```
Foo:     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Bar:     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
         diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
         aliquam erat volutpat.

FooBar:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Foo:     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
         diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
         aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
         nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut
         aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  Duis autem vel eum iriure
         dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,
         vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et
         accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum
         zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
```

Can you please help me?

If my whole way of solving this problem using unordered list seems wrong, please suggest me the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wrap the non span content in a tag like `<p>` then you can use this CSS to get what you want:

```
li .key {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Bjpzm/11/)

Note that `display:table-cell;` doesn't work in IE<8

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position the key, then adjust CSS of the li as needed. http://jsfiddle.net/Bjpzm/19/

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:6em;
}

li .key {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lone,

Best practice would be wrap your text with one more element and use float to key and margin to text wrapper.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="key">Foo:</span>
        <span class="keyDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="key">Bar:</span>
        <span class="keyDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

li .key {
    width: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
}

.keyDesc {
    margin-left:7em;
    display:block;
}
```

Done! This way even if you dont have key, keyDesc items are always aligned with other keyDesc.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mp4PG/